# How can I consume a .asmx web service using C++?

Tags: c++, web-services

Hey I am trying to use this USGS web service:
http://gisdata.usgs.gov/XMLWebServices/TNM_Elevation_Service.php

and I am a little unsure of how to do it in C++. I used WebRequests to use a Google Maps service but I don't know how to specify my parameters to this service in a WebRequest. Any tips?

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that you use C++ for this?

Comment: I know that this would be easier with C# or something of the sort but I would prefer to use C++. If it not possible, then I could switch to a different language.

Comment: It's possible, just that C++ isn't necessarily the best tool for this job. I've posted an answer below that has a 3rd party tool that shoudl make writing a webservice client easier in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hard set on using C++, the easiest way to consume the webservice is to find a 3rd party library that consumes WSDL's and generates the necessary code for you.

I came across [wsdlpull](http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/) via a web search.